# Validating member List variables for null values

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot, collections, java-8

The structure that I have is something like below:

```
Class A{
    String str;
    int i;
    List<B> bs;
    C c;
    @NotNull
    List<D> ds;
}

Class B{
    @NotNull
    List<E> es;
}

Class C{
    List<String> s;
}

Class E{
    @NotNull
    List<String> s;
}
```

For the list variables that are annotated with @NotNull I need to throw validation error if any of them variables has one or more null objects. While for the other list variables I just need to remove the nulls;
What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Use this library https://github.com/jirutka/validator-collection, it has annotations, \@EachNotNull, @EachNotEmpty etc

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the library, would prefer not to add a library for validation. Also the DTO classes are generated automatically thru swagger code-gen and are packaged in a jar. Can't edit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define custom annotation for validating.

so define custom annotation like bellow.

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER,ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidateListValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidateList {
}
```

and implement `ValidateListValidator` like this:

```
public class ValidateListValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateList, List<Object>> {

private ValidateList validateList;
@Override
public void initialize(ValidateList validateList) {
    this.validateList = validateList;
}

@Override
public boolean isValid( List<Object> list, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    return list.stream().noneMatch(Objects::isNull);
  }

 }
```

and for test it

```
@Test
public void test() {
    boolean valid = validator.isValid(Arrays.asList("test","this",null),context);
    assertThat(valid, is(false));
}
```

Comment: I went with this approach. Thanks Hadi.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using validation 2.0+ you can put annotation inside: `List<@NotNull String> s;`

Comment: List<@NotNull String> tried this, doesn't seem to be working. Still accepting nulls, not throwing validation exception..

Comment: How do you check constraint problems? Are you using a validator as an object or by some proxy?

Comment: Thru rest API. The annotation is put on DTO fields that get populated with POST request payload.

Comment: Which version of bean validation are you using? Did you put `@Valid` annotation on object in interface also?

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code that I wrote, just a few tweaks to the code that Hadi posted. I hope it helps:
**Annotation:**

```
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;


@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ListValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidList {
  String message() default "Null values are not allowed in array fields.";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**Validator Class:**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class ListValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidList, List<? extends Object>> {

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(List<? extends Object> list, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return list.stream().noneMatch(Objects::isNull);
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(ValidList constraintAnnotation) {}
}
```